# how to fix xampp control panel mysql starts then stops from running

Tags: mysql, xampp

[image]

ive tried solutions such as . changing the mysql ports to 3307 and adding 
innodb_force_recovery=1 to my.ini but still it wont work

Comment: Any mysql running? confirm and check

Answer (score 0):

This problem was occurring for me.  It was happening because I had installed XAMPP in the `Program Files (x86)` folder.  During the XAMPP install it says DO NOT install it there, but I had misunderstood.

I uninstalled and reinstalled to C:\Xampp and it all works fine now.  This is basically a permissions issue.